# How can I add .p12 cert to react-native request

Tags: ios, react-native, ssl

I'm not good with certificates etc but I need to add this certificate in order to be able to use this API.

I've been trying to use react-native-ssl-pinning like this

```
        import {fetch} from 'react-native-ssl-pinning';

        ...

        fetch('https://appapi2.test.bankid.com/rp/v5.1/auth', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            endUserIp: ip,
        }),
        sslPinning: {
            certs:["FPTestcert3_20200618"]
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log("inner " + error))
```

But in the console I just get :

```
 LOG  smaller The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “appapi2.test.bankid.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

The documentation for react-native-ssl-pinning only talks about .cer files. I tried converting .p12 cert to .cer but still no luck.

I have also added the cert to Copy Bundle Resources in xcode

Testing on iPhone 13, ios 15.2

here is link for cert to download https://www.bankid.com/assets/bankid/rp/FPTestcert3_20200618.p12 and password is qwerty123 (its just a test cert open for public)

Comment: I know it's late, but did you find a solution?

Comment: @P-ABouly For my case I had this cert to communicate with a third party service. It shouldn't be distributed on each app, but rather my backend should act as a gateway to the thirdparty, and the backend should have the cert when doing communication with the third party service.

App -> my backend(cert is stored here) -> request to third party(cert in request)